# How to fix 'No provider for service' error?

Tags: angular

I get an error:

> "Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): Error: No provider for ServiceModuleService! Error: No
>   provider for ServiceModuleService!"

Here is some code.

app.module.shared.ts:

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { ServiceModuleListComponent } from './components/service-module-list/service-module-list.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/shared/header/header.component';
import { ServiceModuleService } from './components/shared/service-module.service';
import { ServiceModuleComponent } from './components/service-module/service-module.component';

export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ServiceModuleListComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        ServiceModuleComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'servicemodulelist', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'servicemodulelist', component: ServiceModuleListComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'servicemodulelist' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [ServiceModuleService]
};
```

app.module.client.ts:

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
        sharedConfig.providers
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app.component.ts

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

service-module.component.ts:

```typescript
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceModule } from '../shared/service-module.type';

@Component({
    selector: 'service-module',
    templateUrl: './service-module.component.html'
})
export class ServiceModuleComponent {
    @Input() serviceModule: ServiceModule

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

service-module-list.component.ts:

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceModule } from '../shared/service-module.type';
import { ServiceModuleService } from '../shared/service-module.service';
import { ServiceModuleComponent }from '../service-module/service-module.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'service-module-list',
    templateUrl: './service-module-list.component.html'
})
export class ServiceModuleListComponent implements OnInit {
    serviceModules: ServiceModule[];

    constructor(private serviceModuleService: ServiceModuleService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.serviceModuleService.getServiceModuleItems()
            .then(serviceModuleItems => {
                this.serviceModules = serviceModuleItems;
            });
    }
}
```

service-module.service.ts:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ServiceModule } from './service-module.type';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceModuleService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getServiceModuleItems() {
        return this.http.get('api/ServiceModuleItems')
            .map(response => response.json() as ServiceModule[])
            .toPromise();
    }
}
```

service-module.type.ts:

```typescript
    export class ServiceModule {
    idx: number;
    applicationName: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    description: string;
}
```

Basically at this point, on startup the app must display a list of entries I have on a SQL table, and the service calls an API to get that, but am stuck on this issue now with the error message.

Comment: Wow. I'm on the Angular doc team, so have seen lots of code ... but never seen any Angular code like this. I don't have time right now to watch the linked video to understand why the modules are done so convoluted, but the one thing I did notice is that `...sharedConfig.imports` has three dots before it but `sharedConfig.providers` does not. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I took out the 3 dots, it's still the same

Comment: service-module-list.component.ts uses ServiceModuleService to fetch the data, and in the html it binds the results to service-module.component.ts with *ngFor. This is just a master detail app and there are many examples of this and they seem to structured in a similar way, so I do not get what part of it is "convoluted", but I am open to constructive criticism.

Comment: It's just the module set up. I find that most developers have trouble with the basics of setting up modules. Having the `app.module.shared.ts` seems to make the module set up more convoluted/complex than it needs to be. But I'll try to make time to watch the video to understand the purpose of this sharedConfig piece ... to understand what it is "sharing" this configuration with.

Comment: BTW ... that error often means that the service is missing from the Angular module, hence the reason I thought it might be something here: `    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
        sharedConfig.providers
    ]`

Comment: Ok thank you. But the scaffolding tool made it a bit different than in the video. I am lost with how to start, what tools to use etc., there are so many versions in a short time already, and a book I started with was a year old and it was too old, because I got stuck and started over. It used Typings etc and when I googled it I saw that was the old way.The book was ASP.NET Core and Angular 2 by Valerio De Sanctis.

Comment: sharedConfig.providers was not there, I added it in desperation.

Comment: Yes, that is a real problem right now. There is no "one way" to do Angular with ASP.NET Core. I understand that there is a lot of work going on with regard to the tooling right now (which may be why the video does not match the code already) and expect it to get better over time.

Comment: Many .NET developers I know are currently using Angular with the Angular CLI and editing it with something like VSCode. The Angular CLI generates the Angular code for you. And then using VS 2017 to build the Web API piece separately. That seems to be working for them ... at least until the tooling for Angular within VS 2017 is more polished/complete.

Comment: Maybe it is a routing problem, because when I put "http://localhost:51133/api/servicemoduleitems" in the url I see the raw data and that is not what I expected.

Comment: You may also want to consider watching some of these: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents and https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-cli/table-of-contents

Comment: "localhost:51133/api/servicemoduleitems" this is just executing your Web API ... not your Angular app, so it would be correct to just see the raw data. (And it means your Web API is working!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dug into this syntax a bit more:

```typescript
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...sharedConfig.imports
],
```

The '...' here is the JavaScript spread operator. It ensures that the contents of the imports is added here and not the array itself. One of my colleagues explained it like this:

```typescript
imports: [
  a,
  b,
  c,
  sharedConfig.imports
]
```

you end up with (which puts the array in)

```typescript
imports: [a, b, c, [what_shared_config_has]]
```

instead of what you want (the values from the array)

```typescript
imports: [a, b, c, what_shared_config_has]
```

So this needs to have the spread operator as well:

```typescript
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
    ...sharedConfig.providers
]
```

Answer (score 6):

I could not paste this much code in a comment, so I'm pasting it here. But this is what my modules look like with my services:

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list.component';
import { ProductDetailComponent } from './product-detail.component';
import { ProductDetailGuard } from './product-guard.service';

import { ProductFilterPipe } from './product-filter.pipe';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent },
      { path: 'product/:id',
        canActivate: [ ProductDetailGuard],
        component: ProductDetailComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductDetailComponent,
    ProductFilterPipe
  ],
  providers: [
    ProductService,
    ProductDetailGuard
  ]
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

I'm not sure what the { provide: ...} piece is for, but you could just add your ServiceModuleService here.

```typescript
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
    ServiceModuleService
]
```